# Does texture baking use the GPU or CPU?

Tags: baking

Is baking textures a GPU or CPU process? I just started with baking textures and my GPU died about a week back. If I got a new (supported) GPU, would it bake off that and be faster or still go off the CPU and take a while?

Answer (score 1):

Blender currently comes with two render engines: Blender Render and Cycles. You can switch between them in the top toolbar, in the field farthest to the right. If you haven't touched it, it says 'Blender Render'.

[image]

In Blender Render, you can't choose between the CPU and GPU for rendering, it will detect what's available and chooses itself. If you install a new graphics card, it will switch to it.

In Cycles, you can set it to use the GPU, or use the CPU, under Render section, at the top of the Render tab in the Properties panel, in the field that says Device

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that materials for different render engines are not interchangeable, so materials created for cycles can only be baked on cycles, and the same applies for blender internal. Once materials have been baked, then they can be applied as an image texture on either render engine (or other 3D apps)